# Issue with sql join with product/printer exercices

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Relations](http://www.sql-ex.ru/):

- Product(maker, model, type)
- Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen)
- PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd)
- Printer(model,price, color, price)

I am now trying to find the maker of the cheapest color printer

My Query:

```
select maker, price from
product join printer 
on product.model=printer.model
where color='y' and price <= all(select price from printer where color='y')
```

the result is correct; however the error message is

> Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available)
>   database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking
>   database.
>   * Wrong number of records (less by 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler way is by using `Top` keyword with `order by` to find the printer with minimum price. This will avoid the `Sub query`

Join the result back with `product` table to find the `maker`

```
SELECT a.maker,b.price
FROM   product a
       JOIN(SELECT TOP 1 price,
                         model
            FROM   printer
            WHERE  color = 'y'
            ORDER  BY price ASC) b
         ON a.model = b.model
```

**Update :** For Mysql use this.

```
SELECT a.maker,b.price
FROM   product a
       JOIN(SELECT  price,
                         model
            FROM   printer
            WHERE  color = 'y'
            ORDER  BY price ASC limit 1) b
         ON a.model = b.model
```

Comment: you should add b.price on top. Even then, I'm getting the correct result, but the same error message

Comment: @Bob Actually where you are running this query. You won't get this error in `SSMS`

Comment: I'm using http://www.sql-ex.ru/ which I think is MySQL 5.5.11, PostgreSQL 9.0, and Oracle Database 11g

Comment: @Bob can you share the sample data of these two tables in question. Btw then why the question is tagged with `Sql Server`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT Prd.Maker, Pri.Price
FROM Product Prd
INNER JOIN Printer Pri
    ON Prd.model = Pri.model
WHERE Pri.price = (
        SELECT MIN(Price)
        FROM Printer
        WHERE Color = 'Y'
        )
    AND Pri.Color = 'Y'
```

You'd be overcomplicating things by trying to use `ALL`. Just use a simple subquery to return the minimum price for a color printer.

Comment: the result is correct, just like mine. the error message is still the same

Comment: @Bob Error message? You get an error message with my query?